# Sketch the set of complex numbers that satisfy $|z| = 1$

Tags: complex-numbers

I know that $z = a + bi$, therefore $\sqrt{a^{2} + b^{2}} = 1$.

I then substituted in $(x,y)$ for $(a,b)$ as coordinates and it creates a circle on the graph $x^2 + y^2 = 1$.

I am not too sure what to do next though.

Comment: It might be helpful to sketch a few points by inspection and see what comes out. Try $x=0,1,-1$ and others between zero and one and see what y-values you get, and plot those points!

Comment: $|u-v|\,$ is the distance between points $u$ and $v$ in the complex plane, so $|z|=|z-0|$ is the distance between $z$ and the origin $0$. Now, the locus of points at constant distance from a fixed point is $\dots$

Comment: @DavidP thank you, I'll be sure to try it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, the circle is the set of all points of the plane that are at a given distance from a given point (the center). In particular the circle of radius 1 centered at the origin is the set

$C=\{(x,y)\in{\mathbb{R}^2} : \|(x,y)-(0,0)\|=\|(x,y)\|=1\} $
(with $\|(x,y)\|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$).

Then $C=\{(x,y)\in{\mathbb{R}^2} : x^2+y^2=1\}$, because

$(x,y)\in{C}$ if and only if $\|(x,y)\|=1$ if and only if $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=1$ if and only if $x^2+y^2=1$.

Then the set that you're looking for is the circle of radius 1 at the origin.

Comment: "circule of radio" should be "circle of radius", same with "circule".

Comment: Sorry, I'm not a native english speaker so my keyboard is no set in English:), but thank you.

Comment: @AlexeyCortés thank you, the explanation was easy to understand :)

Answer (score 0):

The wanted sketch is a circle with center the beginning of the axis, i.e. the point $(0, 0)$ and radius $1$. You want all the complex numbers that satisfy $|z|=1$, so all of those form a circle.